# Object vs. function prototype properties - which should predominate?

Tags: javascript, properties, prototype

I have the following code:

```js
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'json', {
    configurable: true, enumerable: false, writable: true,
    value: function() { return 'Object.json' }
});
function Body() {
    return 1
}
Object.defineProperty(Body.prototype, 'json', {
    configurable: true, enumerable: false, writable: true,
    value: function() { return 'Body.json' }
});
console.log(Body.json())
```

which, when I run I get an unexpected result:

> Object.json

I gather that a function is an object, in the loosest sense of the word (because `typeof` will return different values) and that therefore, functions may inherit from objects, but if a function is derived from object, I would expect its properties to override or hide those of the base class.  yet, the result shows otherwise

how can this be and how can I get the property defined on the function to override that defined on object?

Comment: If you run your code without the defineProperty(Object.prototype... block you get Body.json is not a function. @robby cornelissen captured why below in the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call `Body.json()`, you're not calling `json()` on an "instance" of `Body`, but on `Body` itself, which inherits from the `Object` prototype.

If you define the property on `Body` itself, it will take precedence when evaluating your `Body.json()` call:

```js
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'json', {
    configurable: true, enumerable: false, writable: true,
    value: function() { return 'Object.json' }
});

function Body() {
    return 1
}

Object.defineProperty(Body, 'json', {
    configurable: true, enumerable: false, writable: true,
    value: function() { return 'Body.json' }
});

console.log(Body.json()); // "Body.json"
```

Alternatively, if you define the property on the `Body` prototype and invoke the method on an instance of `Body`, you will also get the expected result:

```js
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'json', {
    configurable: true, enumerable: false, writable: true,
    value: function() { return 'Object.json' }
});

function Body() {
    return 1
}

Object.defineProperty(Body.prototype, 'json', {
    configurable: true, enumerable: false, writable: true,
    value: function() { return 'Body.json' }
});

console.log(new Body().json()); // "Body.json"
```